# Mongodb query collection b based on output of collection A

Tags: python, mongodb

I Have `2` collections in my DB

**Collection_A :**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("51156a1e056d6f966f268f82"),
    name: "priya",
    created_time: "16-07-2015 11:05",
    group_id: "648856e9e5304d"
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("51156a1e056d6f966f268f81"),
    name: "Derick Rethans",
    created_time: "17-07-2015 11:05",
    group_id: "8856e9e5304d"
}
```

**Collection B :**

```
{
group_id : "648856e9e5304d"
group_name: "Art"
}
```

I want to write a python script which will query `collection A` and get the documents based on time (like docments from `16` to `17`). And query `Collection B` for `group_name` using `group_id` from `collection A`. Below is my code where im writing the output into `csv` file.

```
with open('example.csv', 'a') as f:
   for x in db.Collection_A.find():
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, x.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(x)
```

How to alter my code to output range by `date` and `group_name`.

Comment: Could you possibly make a little more effort to acutally represent your MongoDB document structure? The "text" here is invalid for both MongoDB and python. Please show what you really have as it makes "all the difference in the world" to how to actually give a correct response to your question.

Comment: Have edited the MongoDB document structure.